# ROSBag C++ API -- reading message Header

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a C++ (*) program that reads in a bagfile, and needs to be able to access a message's header timestamp (not the one rosbag records itself), if it has one.

How can I do this using ROSBag's API?

- I'm rewriting an existing Python script that's really slow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50994/rosbag-c++-api----reading-message-header/) by [jrvanwhy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3837/jrvanwhy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrvanwhy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3837/jrvanwhy/) on 2012-12-24**:
Thank you, Lorenz -- I was afraid that that was the answer.
(I couldn't find the button to comment on an answer, so I'm doing it here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that only if you know the type of the messages at compilation time. In that case, you can use the `instantiate` method of the class `MessageInstance`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1